# Build a field-lookup-query using the value of another field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Creating a mini-database with access, i came across this problem:

For the background, i have two tables:

```
 Table: Items        and    Table: Actions
ID(PK)    Name             ID(PK)    Name
------------------         ----------------
 1        Thing1            1        Move
 2        Thing2            2        Delete
 3        Thing3
```

I created a query that lists available actions for each item:

```
 Query: AvailableActions
Item_ID    Action_ID
------------------------
 1          2                 //Thing1 can be deleted
 2          1                 //Thing2 can be moved
 2          2                 //Thing1 can be deleted
 (no more records)
```

Now i want to populate a third table that lists the history of objects

```
 Table: History
ID(PK)    Item_ID    Action_ID
----------------------------------
 1         1          2
 2         1          2
 3         2          1
 4         2          2
```

So i'm trying to make a lookup-field for Action_ID, where i can only pick values that are allowed for the choosed item. However, be it in design mode or SQL mode, i can't get the value of that field.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: If you are creating a "history table" then you need a date field to distinguish current actions from previous actions. You also only need to append new data to the history table only if the current actions are different from the previous actions. Don't see the point of have a PK on the history table -- you have two 3's so can't be a PK any way!

Comment: Regarding the date field, i kept the example simple and omitted the 'timestamp' field. and that douple 3 on PK is a typo -editing the post right now-.
i use to put a PK on every table when i did SQL, is anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as i stated in comments, the only way i achieved this goal is by  adding a sub-form to the Items form. (unable to specify this with the structure only, as those Available_actions are computed depending on that same History table)

Answer (score 0):

Before you sort out the UI (mop the floor...), ensure you have the required constraint on the table (...fix the leak) e.g. [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access/HP030704831033.aspx) SQL DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE History ADD
   CONSTRAINT fk__history__AvailableActions
   FOREIGN KEY (Item_ID, Action_ID)
   REFERENCES AvailableActions (Item_ID, Action_ID);
```

...assuming you already have the required unique constraint on `AvailableActions (Item_ID, Action_ID)`.

Comment: Hello,
I'm somehow confused with the mixed GUI (code+designer), but for this History table, the Action field is a 'Action'-ID.
The problem is that Available actions (that is a query, not a table) are computed depending on the precedent actions (to match the workflow process).
It seems to me that i can't do the job with the structure, i have to build a dedicated form to insert data into History, fetching available actions for the chosen Item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of actions that can be applied to Item X then you can generate this with:

```
SELECT Actions.ID, Actions.Name FROM Actions INNER JOIN AvailableActions 
    ON Actions.ID = AvailableActions.ActionID WHERE Actions.Item_ID = X
```

When you talk about deleting "Thing 1", do you actually intend to delete the record from the table or does that record proxy for something else (like a disk file).  If you actually delete it, you will have trouble establishing a PK / FK relationship between Items and AvailableActions if that was your intent.

Comment: There's nothing about deleting records there, just a random verb (replace it by one you like: Sent, Decoratad, ...).

For the queries, i have all the data i need available that are:
* a table of items
* three tables representing the workflow (states, actions and action types)
then i create a query to get the last action of every item (a left join from History on Items, grouped by Item.ID with a field Last(History.ID).
I join this with Actions.State so i get the actual state of an item, then i join with the Workflow query to get AvailableActions.

When i check the records from AvailableActions,

Comment: the data is correct, so there's no big mistakes with structure or queries, i just want to know if it's possible to restrict picking an action into AvailableActions, while keeping the foreign key "History.Action is an Action.ID".